# How to filter out number from array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array var data=["test","10%","abc","20%"];

Now is there any way so that i can filter out and get only the numbers something like `result=["10%","20%"];`

Comment: I doubt those are numbers..

Comment: there are many ways to achieve such result, but show your code first.

Comment: What exactly defines a number you want to keep? Is it digits followed by a `%` symbol? Have you tried writing a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for that and using it with [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: @RyanO'Hara, Why `data.filter(parseInt);` fails ?

Comment: @RayonDabre: That particular expression isn’t a very good idea because `Array#filter` passes three arguments, the second of which is the index of the element being tested and which will be interpreted by `parseInt` as a radix. As for the approach of using `parseInt` in general: I never said it was wrong. It’s hard to know what’s right. Using `if (parseInt(e))` will fail if you didn’t want negative numbers, or if you *did* want zero, or if you didn’t want strings like `0xf`, or if you didn’t want strings like `7#?zQl`, or if you wanted `0.5%`.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Thank you mate.. Did not think about RADIX..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `function`:

**Explanation:** We create a new array and push
all the elements of the old array,
 if the first letter
can be converted into a digit.

```js
var data = ["test", "10%", "abc", "20%"];

function onlyNumbers(array) {
  var newArr = [];
  array.forEach(function(e) {
    if (parseInt(e.charAt(0))) {
      newArr.push(e);
    }
  })
  return newArr;
}

var dataNew = onlyNumbers(data); // <-- ["10%","20%"]

document.write(JSON.stringify(dataNew));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution , you got the question right and got me what i needed

Comment: This will include items such as "1xyz%", "2/()abs" and so on... You only check that the first character is a number.

Comment: @henrikmerlander That is correct. It is only a solution for this type of scenario. If the question or the situation would be more specific, we would have to modify the code.

Comment: Yeah it was just a heads up to the person accepting the answer. Maybe it is not the solution right away but a hint on how to do it. I still think the best solution is to use a regular expression though.

Comment: @henrikmerlander yup,I was stuck with this problem,and John gave me an idea how can I achieve it.. As you said using regex will always be better

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = ["test", "10%", "abc", "20%"];
var result = [];
data.forEach(function(v) {
  if (parseInt(v) > 0) result.push(parseInt(v));
});
console.log(result);
```

If you need not the numbers but the string values, then just replace:
result.push(parseInt(v));    =>    result.push(v);

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [underscore library](http://underscorejs.org/) and do:

```js
var data=["test","10%","abc","20%"];

var result = _.filter(data, function(item) { 
     return item.match(/^(\d+|\d+[.]\d+)%?$/); 
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

And you can do the same without external library:

```js
var data=["test","10%","abc","20%"],
     result = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
     if (data[i].match(/^(\d+|\d+[.]\d+)%?$/)) { 
          result.push(data[i]); 
     } 
 }

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: no need to use any libraries, pure JS `RegExp` object has `exec` method, which does the same.

Answer (score 0):

This will work out your problem and create new array with only good elements:

```
function check_percentage(num){
    var regex = /^(\d+%)$/;
    if (num.match(regex)){
        return true;
    }
}

var result=["babab","fg210%","120%","babab","4214210%","20%"],
    filtered_result=[];

result.forEach(function(k,v){
    if (check_percentage(k)){
        filtered_result.push(k);
    }
});

console.log(filtered_result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LLc1zp9h/